# Extract a specific folder from a zip file using node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a zip file with the following structure:

- download.zip\Temp\abc.txt
- download.zip\Temp\Foo\abc2.txt

I want to extract the content under `Temp` in download.zip to a directory say `D:\work_del`. 
This directory after extraction of zip should have `abc.txt` and `Foo\abc2.txt`
I am using adm-zip module of node but that doesn't seem to help. (Below code for reference).

```
var zip = require('adm-zip');

var file = new zip("D:\\Work\\download.zip");
file.extractEntryTo("Temp", 'D:\\Work_delete', false, true);
```

Any pointers to get the above the scenario working in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

```
var zip = require('adm-zip');

var file = new zip("D:\\Work\\download.zip");
file.extractEntryTo("Temp/abc.txt", 'D:\\Work_delete', false, true);
```

The thing that I noticed is that if you specify the path as `Temp\\1.txt` it doesn't work. So try to avoid backslashes as forward slashes work perfectly fine in Windows with Node.js.

```
var zip = require('adm-zip');

var file = new zip("C:/Users/harslo/Desktop/node/Download.zip");
file.extractEntryTo("Temp/abc.txt", 'C:/Users/harslo/Desktop/node/Work_delete', false, true);
```

If you want to extract all the files inside of a folder use `FolderName/` as described in [adm-zip docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) docs.

**PS - ADM-ZIP extractEntryTo doesn't seem to be working with zips created with Windows Inbuilt "Send to ZIP".**

Comment: Tried that but it doesnt work with zip's created using windows inbuild utility.

Answer (score 0):

```
var zip = require('adm-zip');

var file = new zip("D:/Work/download.zip");
file.extractEntryTo("Temp/", "D:/Work_delete", false, true);
```

Comment: Tried that but it doesnt work with zip's created using windows inbuilt utility.